Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Site does well when faced with a meatier question by someone who knows what they're doing, and retains a small but enthusiastic community. Just needs more interest from folks in that camp, and less confused script-kiddies.

Final Results

Why IDA Pro generated a "j_printf" function call?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Detecting recursive functions in IDA

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


IDA Pro only recognizes my files as BINARY

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)


What is the format of this date time?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


Decompiling Modem Firmware (firmware.bin) with unknown results on binwalk

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


IDA Pro converting to instruction functionality: how to automate.

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


How do I extract a copy of an unknown firmware from a hardware device?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Should I switch from WinDbg to OllyDbg?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


Retrieving encryption/encoding logic from dll

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)


PatchDiff2 Outputting results to a Text File

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

